# Creating a boolean data frame from a data frame in R

Tags: r, shiny

I have a data frame and I want to create a boolean data frame from it. I want to make all unique values of every column in the original data frame as column names in the bolean data frame. To show it using an example:

```
mydata = 
sex   route
m    oral
f    oral
m    topical
f    unknown
```

Then, I want to create

```
    m  f   oral topical unknown
    1  0    1       0       0
    0  1    1       0       0
    1  0    0       1       0
    0  1    0       0       1
```

I am using the code below to create the bolean data frame. It works in **R** but not in **shiny**. What could be the problem?

```
col_names=c()

for(i in seq(1,ncol(mydata))){

 col_names=c(col_names,unique(mydata[i]))
 }


col_names= as.vector(unlist(col_names))

my_boolean= data.frame(matrix(0, nrow = nrow(mydata), ncol =      length(col_names)))

colnames( my_boolean)=col_names

for(i in seq(1,nrow(mydata))){
  for(j in seq(1,ncol(mydata)))
  {
    my_boolean[i,which(mydata[i,j]==colnames(my_boolean))]=1
  }}
```

Comment: Try using model.matrix: `model.matrix(~ sex + route - 1, mydata)` it is cleaner

Comment: I am with @NBATrends, however, `model.matrix(~ sex + route - 1, my data)` will not give you the correct result since one of the categories is used as the baseline. To fix that you can do `cbind(model.matrix(~ sex - 1, mydata), model.matrix(~ route - 1, mydata))`.

Comment: You're going to have to explain what doesn't work in shiny to get help with that part of your question.

Comment: If you are going the `model.matrix` route, its probably clearer to specify the  contrasts `model.matrix(~.-1, mydata, contrasts=lapply(mydata,function(x) diag(nlevels(x))))`

Comment: @AnandaMahto: you are right. I should have mentioned what my problem in Shiny was. Now, it works using the code you provided. Thank you!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few ways you can do this, but I always find `table` the easiest to understand. Here's an approach with `table`:

```
do.call(cbind, lapply(mydf, function(x) table(1:nrow(mydf), x)))
##   f m oral topical unknown
## 1 0 1    1       0       0
## 2 1 0    1       0       0
## 3 0 1    0       1       0
## 4 1 0    0       0       1
```